# Windows Universal app (XAML): textBlock->Text cannot be called with the given argument list

Tags: c++, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app, textblock

I'm trying to set the textBlock equal to the result of some calculations, but for some reason i'm getting the following error: "cannot be called with the given argument list" total is an int.

```
string Result;
ostringstream convert;
convert << total;
Result = convert.str();
textBlock->Text = Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that you are passing a parameter of a wrong type to the textBlock's `Text` property, which expects a `Platform::String`, but you pass a std::string. The MSDN page [Strings(C++/CX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699879.aspx) contains more details on string construction and conversions - also you need to be aware of **ANSI** and **UNICODE** when dealing with strings.

Below is the modified code. Noted that I have changed string to `wstring` (wide string, 16-bit Unicode) so that I can construct a `Platform:String` with it.

```
wostringstream convert;
convert << total;
wstring str = convert.str();
String^ Result = ref new String(str.c_str());
tb1->Text = Result;
```